# Averaging values in a column based on variable in another for line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to be able to average the values across Small.area for every given Big.area.
I then want to plot a line graph with year on the X and the mean of values for small.area  on the Y colored by the big.area - i.e. a line for every value of the averaged small.area colored by Big.area

| Year | Big.area | Small.area | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2011 | A | a | 10 |
| 2011 | A | b | 24 |
| 2011 | B | c | 32 |
| 2011 | B | d | 22 |
| 2012 | A | a | 20 |
| 2012 | A | b | 30 |
| 2012 | B | c | 40 |
| 2012 | B | d | 10 |
| 2013 | A | a | 15 |
| 2013 | A | b | 34 |
| 2013 | B | c | 10 |
| 2013 | B | d | 30 |
| 2014 | A | a | 15 |
| 2014 | A | b | 35 |
| 2014 | B | c | 25 |
| 2014 | B | d | 35 |

so I'd end up with a table like

| Year | Big.area | mean.small.areas |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2011 | A | 17 |
| 2011 | B | 27 |
| 2012 | A | 25 |
| 2012 | B | 25 |
| 2013 | A | 24.5 |
| 2013 | B | 20 |
| 2014 | A | 25 |
| 2014 | B | 30 |

which I can then plot using
`ggplot(df, aes(x= Year, y =mean.small.area, color = Big.area))+geom_line()`

Any ideas?
Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Are those mean  values based on the same example input.  I get different means based on your data `with(df1, mean(Value[Big.area == "A" & Year == 2011]))
[1] 17`

Comment: Yes , apologies i've just edited to add the correct means!

Comment: If the below solution works, please consider to accept solution. thanks

Answer (score 0):

We could use a group by `summarise` approach

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
out <- df1 %>% 
    group_by(Year, Big.area) %>% 
    summarise(mean.small.area = mean(Value, na.rm = TRUE), 
      .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
out
# A tibble: 8 x 3
   Year Big.area mean.small.area
  <int> <chr>              <dbl>
1  2011 A                   17  
2  2011 B                   27  
3  2012 A                   25  
4  2012 B                   25  
5  2013 A                   24.5
6  2013 B                   20  
7  2014 A                   25  
8  2014 B                   30
```

and use the summarised data in `ggplot`

```
ggplot(out, aes(Year, y = mean.small.area, color = Big.area))+
       geom_line() + 
       theme_bw()
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Year = c(2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L), Big.area = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B"), Small.area = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", 
"c", "d"), Value = c(10L, 24L, 32L, 22L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 10L, 
15L, 34L, 10L, 30L, 15L, 35L, 25L, 35L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```